# Make footer stick to bottom in absolute layout

Tags: html, css

I want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page without overlapping content if the page height is more than 100%. I don't know how to achieve that because i cannot change the following css that every page has becaus if i do the website don't work properly because of the transitions.

I know that setting position to relative would fix it, but thats not possible in my case.

Here is the css of the page:

```
.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#footer{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.pt-wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
-webkit-perspective: 1200px;
-moz-perspective: 1200px;
perspective: 1200px;
```

}

Now the footer is always on the bottom of the visible window, so it sometimes overlaps the content.

And the html:

```
  <!-- Page Wrapper -->
  <div class="pt-wrapper">

    <!-- Page 01 -->
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-01">
        <!-- content container -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- row with 1 columns -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 center">
                <h1>¡Bienvenido a tu Nueva Web!</h1>
                <img class="margin-top img-p-01" src="img/36.svg" width="36%" height="36%" alt="">
                <p class="margin-top">La unión perfecta: tu logo, tu dominio, nuestra plataforma!<br>
                Flats2Share esta disponible como software de marca blanca, únicamente para tus propiedades y tus clientes.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <img class="pt-trigger btn-prev" src="img/back.svg" data-animation="1-45-31-2-42-18-34-53-4-52-19-50-7-48-21-11-65-29-6-66-24-52-58-41-62-65-29-36-2-23-21-10-67-46-1-19-41-56-62" data-goto="-2">
          <img class="pt-trigger btn-next" src="img/forward.svg" data-animation="1-45-31-2-42-18-34-53-4-52-19-50-7-48-21-11-65-29-6-66-24-52-58-41-62-65-29-36-2-23-21-10-67-46-1-19-41-56-62" data-goto="-1">
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show you html code, it wil be good if you make a code snippet or jsfiddle.

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick solution.

Add padding-bottom of 70px to your .pt-page element.

Comment: I tried this already but this does not push the footer to the bottom. Only thing is that when you scroll down to the bottom of the page there is 70px space between content and footer.

Comment: So one thing you can do is make a wrapper inside you .pt-page element and put all other content inside that. and then give that wrapper padding-bottom of 70 px.